# Xamarin Forms: Vertical Text Alignment

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have implemented a list in a Xamarin Forms project, using FlowListView, with three columns in a grid. I want to center the text horizontally and vertically. However, on iOS I am facing issues, as I can't center the text vertically in the last column. On Android it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't work on iOS.

This is how it looks like on Android:
[image]

This how it looks like on iOS:
[image]

Some of them are centered while others aren't. I know that the height of each row isn't the same, but that's not the reason - Have tested with different heights.

This is the code for the list:

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="1" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True"
               FlowItemsSource="{Binding PlayersList}">
                <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Period}" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Goals}" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView>
```

As you can see, HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center". What am I missing?

The items I have are from a database.

Comment: Are there any spaces at the end of those (i.e. `113/115 `)

Comment: No, have checked the whole list in the database

Comment: I'd try switching from TextAlignment to `HorizontalOptions="Center"` and `VerticalOptions="Center"` and see if it still happens. I have seen TextAlignment get randomly ignored at times but that's usually been on Android and not iOS.

Comment: @Nick, it doesn't change the alignment. It just separates the column from the rest

Comment: Can you provide more of your code and what version of Forms you are using because I copied your xaml and not seeing the same results on iOS

Comment: What iOS version - custom `ViewCell`?